# Resize iframe & textarea in reverse directions

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, resize

`Iframe` isn't [reziable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) in Firefox. Then I decided to put it in a `div` and resize that instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Resizable Iframe & Textarea</title>
<style>
#top, #bottom {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:10px;
}
#top {
    overflow:auto;
    resize:vertical;
}
iframe, textarea {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    resize:none;
    background:#ccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="top">
        <iframe name="myFrame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var parent = document.getElementById("parent").style.height;
    var top = document.getElementById("top").style.height;
    var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom").style.height;
    window.frames["myFrame"].onresize = function() {
        bottom = parent - top;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RainLover/EY4mR/

Here's what I'd like to achieve: when I enlarge the top `div`, the bottom `div` should get smaller (and vice versa) so the parent `div` size remains fixed.

Note: No `frameset` or jQuery plugin, please! All I need is a simple JavaScript approach to calculate and change the bottom `div` height as soon as I resize the top `div`.

Thanks!

**Update**: The CSS3 resize property isn't well-supported: IE11 doesn't understand it at all and in Chrome/Safari/Opera you can only enlarge the element, not resize it smaller. Therefore I decided to change my approach and instead of a UI resize handle use a slider control. I wonder if you could review my code and let me know what you think:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Resize</title>
    <style>
        textarea,
        iframe {
            display: block;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        textarea {
            background: green;
            resize: none;
        }
        iframe {
            background: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="slide" oninput="resize();" type="range" min="0" max="400" value="200">
    <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
    <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
    <script>
        var slide = document.getElementById("slide");
        var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
        var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");

        function resize() {
            var slideValue = slide.value;
            textarea.style.height = slideValue + "px";
            iframe.style.height = 400 - slideValue + "px";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RainLover/EY4mR/24/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.style.prop` gives you a *value*, which is not updated, when the value of the original property changes. Try this:

```
var topbox = document.getElementById("topbox");
var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");
window.frames["myFrame"].onresize = function() {
    bottom.style.height =  400 - topbox.offsetHeight + 'px';
}
```

`window.top` is a DOM object, which refers to the topmost browser window. In some browsers it may be a protected name, that's why I've changed the name to `topbox`.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqw9S/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work if you add a real source, e.g. http://www.example.com/, to the `iframe`.

Comment: That's due to the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). You're not allowed to detect `onresize` on a third-party window.

Comment: I just updated my code. Would you mind taking a look? Thanks!

Comment: @RainLover Your fiddle seems to work fine. Except in IE, in which `oninput` doesn't seem to fire when slider has been changed. Looks like [IE triggers `onchange`](http://jsfiddle.net/R3apj/1/) from the slider. Also this won't work in older browsers which don't support `type=range`.

Comment: In older browsers, the input `type=range` shows as `type=text` using which you can change the input value. Just tried it in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent").offsetHeight;
window.frames["myFrame"].onresize = function () {
  var top = document.getElementById("top").offsetHeight;
  document.getElementById("bottom").style.height = (parent - top) + "px";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work if you add a real source, e.g. http://www.example.com/, to the `iframe`.

Comment: Ok, i see, so you have to use this: <br/> `var parent = document.getElementById("parent").offsetHeight;
var top = document.getElementById("top");
var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom")
var oldHeight = bottom.offsetHeight;
window.onmousemove = function () {
  var newHeight = parent - top.offsetHeight;
    if(newHeight != oldHeight)
    {
      oldHeight = newHeight;
      bottom.style.height = newHeight + "px";
    }
}`